# Curl using ruby

Tags: curl, ruby-on-rails-3.1, curb, negotiate, httpi

I'm trying to use Curl with SPNEGO negotiate kind of authentication through ruby.

I tried several libraries, but seems like httpi has a way to do it through it's curb adapter like this link:

https://gist.github.com/3179054#comments

I was wondering if there's a way to send JSON data as the "data" part of my curl instead of a file as given in the link. (I mean curl -d option)

My curl goes like this:

> curl -X POST -d "{"id": "12341234","fieldsRequested":["title","state","component"]}" -H >"Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --negotiate -u : >https://abcd.com/find/it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send JSON data with HTTPI/curb, just set your JSON string as the request body as follow:

```
require 'httpi'
require 'curb'
require 'json'  
# ...  

req.body = {"id"=>"12341234","fieldsRequested"=>["title","state","component"]}.to_json

# Then set your custom headers
req.headers = {"Accept" => "application/json", "Content-Type" => "application/json"}
```

Also do not enable the `multipart_form_post` option since multipart POST is not needed:

```
req.auth.gssnegotiate
resp = HTTPI.post req do |http|
  http.use_ssl
end
```